# calling a function in C++ with default arguments

Tags: c++, function, default-value

I have a function `Func(string str,int*i=NULL,int*j=NULL,bool ok=false);`
I called it as `Func(some_string,false);`

And program is crashing..Because the order I'm calling with --is wrong??

Comment: Yes, you can only omit arguments at the end of the argument list, not in the middle.

Comment: Post the code, including the call, and a description of what you mean by "crashing".

Comment: If this actually compiles, it just initialises `i` with `false`, which apparently gets somehow converted to a null pointer value. Does the function work of you call it just as `Func(some_string)`?

Comment: @Angew: Indeed it does. Any integral constant expression equal to zero will convert to the null pointer. `false` is integral, constant, and equal to zero, so it meets all criteria.

Comment: @MSalters I don't know about C++03, but in C++11 [conv.ptr]p1: "A *null pointer constant* is an integral constant expression (5.19) prvalue of **integer type** that evaluates to zero or ..." (emphasis mine). `bool` is integral, but it's not an *integer type*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you wish to specify a value for `ok`, you also have to specify values for all arguments that precede  it.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. The second parameter is expecting a int value and you are passing a bool value. The 3rd and 4th parameters will take NULL and false respectively.